# Angular: Showing only checked items in a checkbox list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

Is it possible to show only a list of checked items in a checkbox list?

What I want to do is select a few items on a checked list and when I press "Show only checked items", I want to toggle between showing **only** the checked items in the checkbox list and showing the entire list with the checked items.

I searched angular's site but wasn't able to find a solution to it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fjoLy5sq/422/

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <label ng-repeat="role in roles">
    <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.roles" checklist-value="role.id"> {{role.text}}
  </label>
  <br>
  <button ng-click="checkAll()">check all</button>
  <button ng-click="uncheckAll()">uncheck all</button>
  <button ng-click="checkFirst()">check first</button>
   <button ng-click="checkFirst()">Show only Checked</button>
  <br><br>
  user.roles {{ user.roles | json }}
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module("DemoApp", ["checklist-model"])
.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.roles = [
    {id: 1, text: 'guest'},
    {id: 2, text: 'user'},
    {id: 3, text: 'customer'},
    {id: 4, text: 'admin'}
  ];
  $scope.user = {
    roles: [2, 4]
  };
  $scope.checkAll = function() {
    $scope.user.roles = $scope.roles.map(function(item) { return item.id; });
  };
  $scope.uncheckAll = function() {
    $scope.user.roles = [];
  };
  $scope.checkFirst = function() {
    $scope.user.roles.splice(0, $scope.user.roles.length); 
    $scope.user.roles.push(1);
  };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new variable in controller:

```
$scope.showAll = true;
```

In a view inverse the value of `showAll` when *Show only Checked* button is clicked:

```
<button ng-click="showAll = !showAll">Show only Checked</button>
```

To show only checked items, use `Array.includes` method, and check that current role is in `user.roles`:

```
<label ng-repeat="role in roles" ng-if="user.roles.includes(role.id)">
  <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.roles" checklist-value="role.id"> {{role.text}}
</label>
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/alexmac/fjoLy5sq/423/)

Comment: Thanks very much, worked beautifully, side question, do you know how to do this in Angular2?  I'm trying to learn how to do things in both but haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Glad that my answer was helpful. Yes, I have an idea how to implement it in ng2+, could you create a new demo on jsfiddle and create a new question? I'll try to answer.